# Creating a JSON Array in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I need to pass a JSON array named "triggers" with components String "trigger", String "triggerID", and int "anxiety" in Flutter. I tried passing in an encoded JSON String, but that resulted in the error message that my String indices must be integers

What I have right now:

```
List<TriggerSubtype> triggerList = [
      TriggerSubtype(
          trigger: "Test add trigger", defaultID: "", anxiety: 1)
    ];
    String chosenTriggerJSON = jsonEncode(triggerList);
    print(chosenTriggerJSON);

postDataResponseRequest('/v1/sample_endpoint',
        data: json.encode({'triggers': chosenTriggerJSON}));
```

Which prints out [{"trigger":"Test add trigger","defaultID":"","anxiety":1}]. How would I make this (chosenTriggerJSON) into a JSON Array, like how Kotlin can use the JSONArray() function

Answer (score 0):

You must to have a method to transform the data, like toJSON.

```
class TriggerSubtype {
  TriggerSubtype(
      {@required String trigger,
      @required String defaultID,
      @required int anxiety})

  String toJSON() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'trigger': trigger,
      'defaultID': defaultID,
      'anxiety': anxiety
    };
    return jsonEncode(map);
  }
}
```

And to call the method you can do it:

```
String chosenTriggerJSON = jsonEncode(trigger.toJSON());
```

To use like a list you must create a new class called

```
class TriggerList{
    
    TriggerList(List<TriggerSubtype> triggers)

    String toJSON(){
    var map = <String, dynamic>{
      'triggers': triggers,
    };
    return jsonEncode(map);
    }
}
```

I recommend you to use this site to help you.

https://jsontodart.com/